# Roman domination number in a tree

Tags: java, graph, tree

I'm trying to implement linear algorithm of roman domination number in trees from page 61-66 of [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.5345&rep=rep1&type=pdf). it almost work but for below graph it returns 6 instead of 8

```
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

can someone help me on this case.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author karo
 */
public class LinearTreeDomination {
    int n;
    int[][] Class;
    int[] Parent;
    private static final int INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE/100;

    public LinearTreeDomination(int[][] graph,int vertex) {
        Class = new int[vertex+1][5];
        Parent = new int[vertex+1];
        n = vertex;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            Class[i][1] = 1;
            Class[i][2] = 2;
            Class[i][3] = INFINITY;
            Class[i][4] = 0;
        }
        Parent[0] = -1;
        boolean[] bool = new boolean[vertex];
        Arrays.fill(bool, false);
        bool[0] = true;
        dfs(graph,bool,0);
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            Parent[i] = Parent[i-1] + 1;
        }

    }

    private void dfs(int[][] graph,boolean[] visited,int index) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            if(graph[i][index] == 1 && index != i){
                if(visited[i] == false){
                    Parent[i] = index;
                    visited[i] = true;
                    dfs(graph,visited,i);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public int doIt(){
        for (int j = 0; j <= n-2; j++) {
            int k = Parent[n-j];
            combine(k,n-j);
        }
        return min(Class[1][1],Class[1][2],Class[1][3]);
    }


    private void combine(int a, int b) {
        int[] ClassPrim = new int[5];

        ClassPrim[1] = min(Class[a][1]+Class[b][1],Class[a][1]+Class[b][2]
                ,Class[a][1]+Class[b][3]);
        ClassPrim[2] = min(Class[a][2] + Class[b][1],Class[a][2] + Class[b][2]
                ,Class[a][2] + Class[b][3],Class[a][2] + Class[b][4]
                ,Class[a][1] + Class[b][4] + 1,Class[a][3] + Class[b][4] + 2
                ,Class[a][4] + Class[b][4] + 2);
        ClassPrim[3] = min(Class[a][3] + Class[b][1],Class[a][3] + Class[b][2]
                ,Class[a][3] + Class[b][3],Class[a][4] + Class[b][2]);
        ClassPrim[4] = min(Class[a][4] + Class[b][1],Class[a][4] + Class[b][3]);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            Class[a][i] = ClassPrim[i];
        }
    }

    private int min(int... values){
        int k = INFINITY;
        for (int val : values) {
            k = Math.min(k, val);
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

---

### Correction

Like J Richard Snape said the problem was at the dfs method, the dfs was for labeling the vertex and I didn't initialize vertex labels. After that we should set Parent Array. the code is a little messy and unreadable I just tried to find answer.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author karo
 */
public class LinearTreeDomination {

    int n;
    int[][] Class;
    int[] Parent;
    int[] Label;
    int Y;
    private static final int INFINITY = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 100;

    public LinearTreeDomination(int[][] graph, int vertex, int from) {
        Y = 0;
        Class = new int[vertex + 1][5];
        Parent = new int[vertex + 1];
        Label = new int[vertex + 1];
        n = vertex;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            Class[i][1] = 1;
            Class[i][2] = 2;
            Class[i][3] = INFINITY;
            Class[i][4] = 0;
        }
        Label[0] = 0;
        boolean[] bool = new boolean[vertex];
        Arrays.fill(bool, false);
        bool[from] = true;
        dfs(graph, bool, from);
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            Label[i] = Label[i - 1] + 1;
        }
        Parent[1] = 0;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int k = Label[i] - 1; k > 0; k--) {
                if (graph[i - 1][getIt(k) - 1] == 1) {
                    counter++;
                    Parent[Label[i]] = k;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void dfs(int[][] graph, boolean[] visited, int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (graph[i][index] == 1 && index != i) {
                if (visited[i] == false) {
                    Y++;
                    Label[i] = Y;
                    visited[i] = true;
                    dfs(graph, visited, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int doIt() {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n - 2; j++) {
            int k = Parent[n - j];
            combine(k, n - j);
        }
        return min(Class[1][1], Class[1][2], Class[1][3]);
    }

    private void combine(int a, int b) {
        int[] ClassPrim = new int[5];

        ClassPrim[1] = min(Class[a][1] + Class[b][1], Class[a][1] + Class[b][2], Class[a][1] + Class[b][3]);
        ClassPrim[2] = min(Class[a][2] + Class[b][1], Class[a][2] + Class[b][2], Class[a][2] + Class[b][3], Class[a][2] + Class[b][4], Class[a][1] + Class[b][4] + 1, Class[a][3] + Class[b][4] + 2, Class[a][4] + Class[b][4] + 2);
        ClassPrim[3] = min(Class[a][3] + Class[b][1], Class[a][3] + Class[b][2], Class[a][3] + Class[b][3], Class[a][4] + Class[b][2]);
        ClassPrim[4] = min(Class[a][4] + Class[b][1], Class[a][4] + Class[b][3]);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            Class[a][i] = ClassPrim[i];
        }
    }

    private int min(int... values) {
        int k = INFINITY;
        for (int val : values) {
            k = Math.min(k, val);
        }
        return k;
    }

    private int getIt(int k) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (Label[i] == k) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any reason that you start from one or not zero here? for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

Comment: @KickButtowski i just wanted to implement exactly like original algorithm to avoid numerical mistakes.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to learn on the practices and code used 15 years ago. 
I would suggest you try to rewrite it yourself while thinking about what it attempts to do and following Java standards and current best practices.
Most likely you will be able to find problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I believe the `dfs()` based labelling for your graph is not working properly and that is causing your problem. I think your `Parent` vector should be `[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 9]` - your program calculates `[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 9]` - which is the same tree structure, but with the nodes labelled in a non-DFS manner.

You can solve that either by

1. making your `dfs()` method pretty clever so that it can detect wrongly numbered nodes connected together in the adjacency matrix, or
2. Changing your adjacency matrix to look like the following, which is the same tree shape and same format, but with the correctly numbered nodes connected

   ```
   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
   ```

#### Detail

It is very hard, from your question alone, to see how your matrix input is related to the algorithm in the paper you link.  In particular - in that paper, the tree structure is entirely defined by the `Parent` vector, but you have introduced a new parameter called `Graph`.

I'm going to assume that your input is an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).  If that's not correct - what follows will be nonsense - please advise in comments.  I'm going to further assume that I don't have to check for loops or anything - so will not consider how that might affect what you're doing (if you need to do these checks programatically - there are [examples on the web](http://cs-people.bu.edu/kvodski/teaching/spring10/solutions/DFS.java)).  Note, though - as you have the diagonal all 1s in the adjacency matrix - it really denotes a graph with a loop on every node.

Your adjacency matrix gives a graph that looks like this:

[image: Unlabelled tree from adjacency matrix]

That should be labelled like this:

[image: Tree labelled per DFS]

Which would give `Parent` values of `[-1,0,1,2,3,4,3,6,7,6,9]` using your indexing.  However, (if you output `Parent` in your constructor), you get this before the loop to make the labels index 1 based:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 2, 7, 8, 0]
```

and this after:

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 8, 9]
```

This is the correct "shape" of tree, but the nodes are not labelled in the right order for DFS (specifically the middle "leg" is numbered bottom up).

If you mock up the correct value of parent by simply inserting

```
Parent = new int[]{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 6, 9};
```

at the end of the Constructor, you will get the answer you expect (Roman domination number == 8).  This might hint we're on the right track.  Note that this is basically just debugging...

#### Comment

I can see that you've retained 1 based indexing for correspondance with the paper.  I think this is a bad idea - it makes Java very hard to read.  I suggest you replace with 0 based indexing and, if I get some time, I'll post a solution using your code but with the 0 based indexing and `dfs()` fixed.